# Mongoid accepts_nested_attributes_for issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have got this relations

```
class Bird
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :eggs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :eggs
end

class Egg
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :bird
end

bird = Bird.new
#=> #<Bird...
bird.eggs.build
#=> #<Egg...
bird.save
bird.reload.eggs
#=> []
```

**Where are my eggs!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `has_many` to

```
has_many :eggs, :autosave => true
```